# Ripple effect opacity in React Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI https://material-ui.com/.

How to change opacity of ripple effect using normal button?

```
<Button className={classes.ripple} />

ripple: {
   color: "red",
}
```

I found it in documentation:

```
 /* Styles applied to the internal `Ripple` components `rippleVisible` class. */
  rippleVisible: {
    opacity: 0.3,
    transform: 'scale(1)',
    animation: `mui-ripple-enter ${DURATION}ms ${theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut}`,
  },
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  btn: {
      height: 60,
      fontSize: 18,
      textTransform: "none"
  },
  buttonRipple: {
      opacity: 0.3,
      transform: "scale(1)",
      animation: `ripple-effect 550ms ${theme.transitions.easing.easeInOut}`
  },
  "@keyframes ripple-effect": {
    "0%": {
        transform: "scale(0)",
        opacity: 0.1
    },
    "100%": {
        transform: "scale(1)",
        opacity: 0.9
    }
  }

})


render: function () {

  return (
    <Button
        className={classes.btn}
        TouchRippleProps={{ classes: { rippleVisible: classes.buttonRipple } }}
    >

  )
}
```

You will need to define a new keyframe since the opacity is controlled by a keyframe animation where it takes the start and end opacity. If the button is long pressed then the opacity will be shown from the opacity defined in "buttonRipple" class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, great. Thank you

Comment: Please mark the answer if it works for you. It would be helpful for others too.

Comment: Of course. Do you know maybe if it is possible to do it without keyframes?

Comment: To achieve ripple effect, you will need to use animation. isn't it ?
We are just changing the final opacity value in keyframes.

Comment: You're declaring styles but never use it.